# k-Anonymity for object-orientated databases

Tags: database-theory

Based on this theoretical work of Latanya Sweeney about k-anonymity:

> Definition 2.1 (Quasi-Identifier)

Let 
[image] 
be a table. A quasi-identifier of 
[image] 
is a set of attributes 
[image] 
whose release must be controlled.

> Definition 2.2 (k-anonymity)

Let
[image] 
be a table and 
[image]
be the quasi-identifiers associated with it. 
[image]
is said to satisfy k-anonymity if for each quasi-identifier 
[image] 
each sequence of values in
[image] 
appears at least with 
[image] 
occurrences in 
[image] 
.

---

Can anyone approve these next assumptions on an object-oriented approach?

> Definition 1.1 (object-table)

Let 
[image] 
and 
[image]
 be a table and 
[image]
 a mapping from the original table 
[image]
 to the object-table
[image]
.

> Definition 1.2 (oject-space)

Let there be a space of all alterations 
[image]
 of one object-attribute 
[image]
 and a space of functions 
[image]
 mapping between those.

> Definition 1.2b

[image]
 and 
[image]
 so
[image]
 is the non-anonymizing-function.

> Definition 1.3 (quasi-identifier)

Let 
[image]
 be a the qausi-identifier regarding the space 
[image]
 as 
[image]

> Definition 1.4

Let 
[image]
 be a second table and 
[image]
 be the quasi-identifiers associated with it. 
[image]
 is said to satisfy k-anonymity if for each quasi-identifier
[image]
 each sequence of values in 
[image]
 appears at least with 
[image]
occurrences in 
[image]
.

So there is a bridge between the k-anonymity and the k-anonymity inbetween space of attributes and their anonymisations